# Software Package List installed in Linux

Tags: linux

I have RedHat Linux on which there are some softwares installed like:

- Standard C++ Library 33-3.2.3-47.3
- WebSphere MQ Client 6.0.2.6
- IBM Global Security Kit 7.0.4.11
- IBM Key Management Tool 6.0 or above
- Tivoli Data Exchange 4.4.0.0

I want to know if there is a way to get this list by executing some command from the Command line, such that when I execute the command, it prompts me with whatever is there and if anything is missing then it can be installed

Comment: How is this tool you propose supposed to know what is missing?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the RPM names for all of those packages, you can use the `verify (-V)` option to the `rpm` command to identify missing files or what has been modified since it was installed.

For example:

```
rpm -V compat-libstdc++-33
rpm -V gsk7bas
```

If nothing has changed, the command will produce no output.  However, if a change is detected, you'll receive a report like this:

```
# rpm -V openssh-server
S.5....T.  c /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

From the rpm man page:  "Verifying a package compares information about the installed files in the package with information about the
       files  taken  from  the package metadata stored in the rpm database.  Among other things, verifying compares
       the size, MD5 sum, permissions, type, owner and group of each file."

If you don't know the RPM names, try this:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat="%{NAME}\t%{VENDOR}\n" | egrep -v "Red Hat"
```

Comment: Also how can I check the Linux SCB Standard Build AS4.0 i.e. teh base OS. Can that also be verified using rpm?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  Are you asking how to check if the system is a RHEL 4AS build?
`cat /etc/redhat-release`.

Comment: Yeah I want to check what is the base Operating System is AS4.0 (Linux SCB Standard Build). Which command can I use to check this?

Answer (score 1):

Try `rpm -qa` to get a list of installed packages